# Is code signing necessary for Windows Mobile applications?

Tags: windows-mobile, distribution, code-signing

I want to create a windows mobile application and distribute it from my website but I don't want to buy a code signing certificate.
I have HTC Diamond2 smartphone (WM6.1) and it allows me to run my not signed app. It gives me no warnings though my app connects to the net and makes calls. Also, several years ago I had a Windows Mobile 4.0 device and it also did not require signing. So I always thought that code signing is not necessary for windows mobile. But recently I read that it can be required???

So the question is: if I distribute my app from my website worldwide, how many users will not be able to use it because it is not signed? I mean what percentage? Maybe it's different in different countries? Maybe in countries where most phones are sold locked the signing is required, and in countries where phones are usually sold unlocked the signing is not required?

Please enlighten me in this matter.

Comment: I've posted a way to remove the code signing requirement of some Windows Mobile devices in C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different levels of security that the device manufacturer can specify when building the OS. At the highest level, you need to have your application signed. At the lowest level, you can copy an executable to the device and run it. There are intermediate levels that will allow applications installed via CAB file to run even if they are not signed. In general, if the device is purchased from a cell phone carrier, you will probably need to sign the app (or hack the device). If the device is purchased from the manufacturer and you add your own SIM card, there is a good chance it won't need signing. In my experience, more WM6 devices have the higher security settings than WM5 devices.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify some registry keys to make it so any executable can be run on the device.  On a default Windows Mobile 6.0 device, you would see the "Do you want to allow *_*.EXE to run?" popup.  If you click yes and the program makes the registry modifications and restarts the device then any application can run.

```
// Checks to see if the policies in the registry need to be adjusted to allow
// an unsigned program to run.  This also affects WCELOAD.EXE as well.
// This is needed to run some programs on Windows Mobile 6 from an unsigned application.
void UpdatePolicy()
{
    BOOL bPolicyNeedsUpdate = FALSE;
    DWORD dwExistingPolicy = 0;
    DWORD dwNewPolicy = 0;
    HKEY hKey = NULL;
    DWORD dwSize = sizeof(DWORD);

    RegCreateKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, _T("Security\\Policies\\Policies"), 0, NULL, 0,
        KEY_ALL_ACCESS, NULL, &hKey, NULL);
    // See if the policy has already been adjusted.
    if (hKey != NULL)
    {
        DWORD dwType = 0;
        RegQueryValueEx(hKey, _T("0000101a"), NULL, &dwType, (LPBYTE)&dwExistingPolicy, &dwSize);
        if (dwExistingPolicy != 1)
            bPolicyNeedsUpdate = TRUE;
    }
    if (bPolicyNeedsUpdate)
    {
        // Adjust the policy
        dwNewPolicy = 1;
        RegSetValueEx(hKey, _T("0000101a"), NULL, REG_DWORD, (const BYTE*)&dwNewPolicy, dwSize);
        RegSetValueEx(hKey, _T("00001001"), NULL, REG_DWORD, (const BYTE*)&dwNewPolicy, dwSize);
        dwNewPolicy = 40;
        RegSetValueEx(hKey, _T("00001005"), NULL, REG_DWORD, (const BYTE*)&dwNewPolicy, dwSize);
        dwNewPolicy = 144;
        RegSetValueEx(hKey, _T("00001017"), NULL, REG_DWORD, (const BYTE*)&dwNewPolicy, dwSize);
        // Reboot so the changes take effect
        Reboot();
    }
    RegCloseKey(hKey);
}

void Reboot()
{
    SetSystemPowerState(NULL, POWER_STATE_RESET, 0);
}
```